# Prevent users from seeing other profiles on DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I'm using DNN 7.1.2 and what I want to do is prevent users from navigate on other profiles and see their usernames - make the profiles private (I've already disabled all the info from Profile Settings).

If I login on any user and than paste this url in the browser http://example.com/ActivityFeed/tabid/58/UserID/93/language/en-US/Default.aspx , I can see this guy's username, and if I increment the UserID I cand see the next users.

My initial solution was a rewriterule in IIS for url: ActivityFeed/tabid/58/UserID/*/language/en-US/Default.aspx but the problem is that the edit profile url is similar to this and this will prevent users to edit the profiles, which is not acceptable :)

Does anyone know a solution or how can it be done with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this using code.

In the file DesktopModules\Admin\ViewProfile\ViewProfile.ascx.cs I added the following lines:

```
if(!IsUser)
{
    Response.Redirect(GetRedirectUrl(), true); // Redirect to homepage
    return;
}
```

If you want show a message like "Access Denied" you can use:

```
Response.Redirect(Globals.NavigateURL("Access Denied"), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be a lot simpler to set profile properties to be not publicly viewable.

And, your method will be overwritten by an upgrade.

Comment: hi @Joe thanks for your response. How do you do that?